# Copying google apps script with forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running into a strange issue that is causing me considerable difficulty hoped someone her might have some insight.

I have a form that is accepting responses and sending the results to a sheet. I've written an additional onsubmit script that then marks up some other sheets both in order to facilitate tracking and to provide a prefilled url that can be sent next time the form needs to be submitted.

The forms are for student data collection and I therefor need three each collecting data about students in different years. My issue is that I can't seem to copy the scripts to the other forms without them ceasing to work.

I have taken the following approaches:

Initially I just tried duplicating the entire form and then changing it, this meant the scripts came along with the copy.

I then tried keeping the duplicated form but deleting out all the script information and copy and pasting the script to a new project within the form.

I then tried creating a new test form and copy and pasting the script to that - again no success.

All attempts have resulted in the data being successfully submitted to the responses sheet but the script either not triggering or failing silently.

I can't see anything in the script I have produced that would cause it to work only on one form but I'm not very experienced in JS and it may be I am not seeing something obvious ( I am aware there are some foolish bits in the script but this is the version I know works).

If anyone can point out anything that would make the script not work for any other forms or can explain how the script can be successfully copied I'd be really grateful.

Code:

```csh
/* onsubmit function that creates a prefilled url and prints to sheet */
function onSubmit(e) {
  var subject = "ICT";
  //generate url
  var url=e.response.toPrefilledUrl();

  var responses = e.response;//e is of type formresponse.
  var name = responses.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/a/rbair.org.uk/spreadsheets/d/1w_rCPJR-O9_fUs1T5HKmaTUsRjk_9JRVRPxV2kJzNMk/edit#gid=0").getSheetByName("Admin");
  update(name, subject);


  //print to cell in feedback sheet
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
   for(i=0; i<100; i++)
   {
     if(data[i][1]==name)
     {
       sheet1.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(url);
     }
  }
}
function test()
{
  var name = "Piers Hartley";
  var subject = "ICT";
  update(name, subject);
}

function update (name, subject)
{
  //var name = "Piers Hartley";
  //var subject = "ICT";
  var msheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/a/rbair.org.uk/spreadsheets/d/1IauIkNCrE95qNAL2KxfJhespEcRWuMXYGzkkjwFnezg/edit#gid=0");
  var refsheet = msheet.getSheetByName("Subject Teachers");
  var track = refsheet.getRange(2,10).getValue();
  var tsheet = msheet.getSheetByName(track);
  var trdr = tsheet.getDataRange();
  var trdata = trdr.getValues();
  var lcol = trdr.getLastColumn();
  var lrow = trdr.getLastRow();
  for(i=0; i<lcol; i++)
  {
    if (trdata [0] [i] == subject)
    {
      for (j=1; j<lrow; j++)
      {
        if (trdata [j] [i] == name)
        {

          tsheet.getRange(i+2, j+1).setValue("Done");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the On Form Submit trigger? (under Resources in the script editor).

Comment: Derp... thanks, I totally missed that - is it permissible to blame it on a 16 hour coding hangover?